# Does a probabilistic universe require absolute simultaneity?

Tags: relativity

Is it true that each and every atom that composes my body has its own reference frame, hence its own simultaneity? Does this mean that every atom that makes up my body has its own "present"? Then what is this perception we feel of the world as just one present?

---

By a probabilistic universe I mean a universe where all events occur probabilistically as opposed to a block universe. Is the relativity of simultaneity compatible with a probabilistic universe? Because I don't think it is.

---

If everything happens the same way in every reference frame and relativity of simultaneity holds true, then one frame would contain events that for the other frame haven't happened yet, just like the Andromeda paradox. And this would be totally deterministic, one even would say predeterministic, with no room for the possibility of a probabilistic universe!

Comment: You have asked this before, and on that occasion we asked you to make clear what you meant by a probabilistic universe. The same applies to this version of your original question. Note that interactions between atoms are ultimately described by quantum field theory which is compatible with special relativity, so if you're asking whether quantum mechanics runs into problems with particles that have different time dilations the answer is *no*.

Comment: By a probabilistic universe I mean a universe where all events occur probabilistically as opposed to a block universe. And I think a probabilistic universe requires absolute simultaneity.

Comment: Then I guess you are asking about the collapse of the wavefunction, so you're asking if special relativity is compatible with quantum mechanics. The answer to that is *yes*.

Comment: BTW, the atoms in your body have low speed relative to one another, so the deviations of their time axes are very tiny.

Comment: @Kim Please provide a complete thought experiment where you see a contradiction or incompatibility. Are you bewildered by how, for instance, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle (about simultaneous measurements) is compatible with the relativity of simultaneity?

Comment: If everything happens the same way in every reference frame and relativity of simultaneity holds true, then one frame would contain events that for the other frame haven't happened yet, just like the Andromeda paradox. And this would be totally deterministic, one even would say predeterministic, with no room for the possibility of a probabilistic universe!

Answer (score 4):

> Is the relativity of simultaneity compatible with a probabilistic universe? Because I don't think it is.

Quantum field theory (QFT) is a theory which is both probabilistic and also obeys special relativity including the relativity of simultaneity. The existence of QFT and its mathematical framework clearly indicate that the relativity of simultaneity is in fact compatible with a universe with probabilistic physics. Furthermore, many experiments show that QFT is an accurate description of this universe.